# How can I execute this t-sql statements using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I need to execute these t-sql statements using c#, for some reasons I do not want to put them in stored procedure.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE mytable
SET col=col 

WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00'  

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: You can find your answer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b.aspx

Comment: Sanity check ... You know that come does nothing useful but blocks other connections for a while, yes?

Comment: The real question is why would you want to? Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish whatever it is you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute that as one batch because ***it is not*** one batch. You cannot put GO in the middle - that separates batches in editors like SSMS but is not actually T-SQL itself.

Your code, however, does not need that GO - so just remove it. Or execute it as two separate batches on the same connection (which is exactly what tools like SSMS will do with this).